# What's the use case of 'respond_to' in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml  { render :xml => @mah_blogz }
end

respond_to do |format|
      format.js
end
```

What's this `respond_to`, `format.html`, `format.xml` and `format.js`? What's their purpose and how do they work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the link to the documentation

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods.html#method-i-respond_to

Its a way of responding to the client based on what they are asking for, if the client asks for HTML, Rails will send back HTML to the client, if they ask for XML then XML.

Answer (score 8):

Say you are doing this:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      def create
        #
        #your code
        #

        respond_to do |format|
          format.xml {render :xml => xxx}
          format.json {render :json => xxx}
          format.html {render xxx}
        end
      end

      def edit
        #
        #your code
        #

        respond_to do |format|
          format.xml {render :xml => xxx}
          format.json {render :json => xxx}
          format.html {render xxx}
        end
      end

    end
```

rather do:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      respond_to :xml, :json, :html

      def create
        #
        #your code
        #

        respond_with xxx

      end

      def edit
        #
        #your code
        #

        respond_with xxx

      end

    end
```

and thats how you keep the code DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself)

Comment: but most of the time, there are other actions. what if you don't want them to respond to those other formats? Simply don't have those files in the app? (e.g. for a `new` action, don't include new.json or new.xml)? Are there any vulnerabilities or bad practices with doing it this way? As long as there is no file to call, I guess there should be no issue, right?

Comment: @gwho: You are free to limit the `respond_to` call to only actions u need using the `:only` parameter. For ex: `respond_to :json, :xml, only: [:new, :create]` works. -- OR -- if you dont want to use `:only`, then just don't write respond_with. Use `render`

Comment: Ah Tahnk you. This seems like a very natural, frequent use case. It's amazing how many blogs/resources tend to skip it, only giving the most simplistic cases.